# Can someone explain MPEG2 TS (Transport Stream) bytes structure with example?

Tags: python, media, bytestream, transport-stream

I'm trying to understand TS bytes structure, I find a source on wikipedia but without example i can't understand totally, I just understand a TS file contains a group of 188 bytes pocket with sync byte 0x47 header and payload data. But i can't understand that how payload data describe a video and audio track information.

Can someone deeply describe TS bytes structure or give me better source where i can understand better.